# fnUpdate the multi td for th with colspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I use `.fnUpdate()` to generate `table` according to data that comes from the database.
http://legacy.datatables.net/ref

I have some teacher in the header of the `table`, and some information in the `td` in the body of the `table`.

I can generate the data in `TDs` but I want to show the multiple `td` bellow one `th`.

#### Problem

I can set the `colspan` for generated `th`, but how I can assign data by fnupdate for each sub td.
**Note: the number of teachers and the number of colspan will assign from DB and we should dynamically check the number of colspan and generate related td's.**

I want to generate output like this by `fnUpdate`
[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" border='1'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">teacher 1</th>
            <th>teacher 2</th>
            <th>teacher 3</th>
            <th colspan="3">teacher 2</th>
            <th>teacher 5</th>
            <th>teacher 6</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon2</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>Edinburgh61</td>
            <td>Edinburgh62</td>
            <td>Edinburgh63</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>Edinburgh3,120</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Does it need to literally be 2 cells under a single header? The easiest solutions involve either 1 cell containing both pieces of data (you can use rowCallback to modify one or the other to contain both), or just simplifying and having a "First Name" and "Last Name" pair of columns. It also wouldn't be TOOoooo hard to just render it as 2 columsn with headers, and use DOM manipulation to shape the header cells into colspanned cells afterwards.

Comment: Sorry! I should say that the number of cells is not static and it will change by DB, example=> a teacher can have 2 or 3 cells that we should be able to assign correct data for each sub TDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Set `bAutoWidth` as `false` while creating `dataTable`

```
const exampleTable = $('#example').dataTable({
  "bAutoWidth": false
});
```

Used `fnAddData()` for adding new row into `dataTable` or to update the whole table use `fnUpdate()`.

See the example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" border='1'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th colspan="3">Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon2</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        const oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
            'bAutoWidth': false
        });
        // Adding New Row
        oTable.fnAddData( ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g','h','i']);

        // Update whole table with new data
        oTable.fnUpdate( ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g','h','i']);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### RESULT of adding new row using `fnAddData()`

[image: Update dataTable using fnAddData()]

### RESULT of update whole table using `fnUpdate()`

[image: Update dataTable using fnUpdate()]

Comment: how about when the colspan not being static and being dynamic and change by fetched data from DB, I want to use the index that we have.

Comment: You can use `createdRow` property while initialization of `dataTable`. `createdRow()` triggers when you add new data using `fnAddData()`. You can write your logic inside this `createdRow()` and update colspan dynamically according to your need.

`'createdRow': function(row, data, dataIndex) {
  // Develop your logic here
 }
});`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which might help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th colspan="3">Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon2</td>

            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>



var teachers = [
    {
        name1: 'Tiger Nixon',
        name2: 'Tiger Nixon2',
        position: 'System Architect',
        office: 'Edingurgh',
        age1: '61',
        age2: '62',
        age3: '63',
        start_date: '2011/04/25',
        salary: '$3200',
    },
    {
        name1: 'Peter Nixon',
        name2: 'Paul Nixon2',
        position: 'System Architect',
        office: 'London',
        age1: '71',
        age2: '72',
        age3: '73',
        start_date: '2014/04/25',
        salary: '$5200',
    },
];

fnUpdate();


function fnUpdate() {
    var table = document.getElementById( 'example' );
    for ( var i in teachers ) {
        var teacher = teachers[i];

        var hr = document.createElement( 'tr' );

        var property = document.createElement( 'td' );

        property.innerText = teacher.name1;
        hr.appendChild( property );

        property = document.createElement( 'td' );
        property.innerText = teacher.name2;
        hr.appendChild( property );

        property = document.createElement( 'td' );
        property.innerText = teacher.position;
        hr.appendChild( property );

        property = document.createElement( 'td' );
        property.innerText = teacher.office;
        hr.appendChild( property );

        property = document.createElement( 'td' );
        property.innerText = teacher.age1;
        hr.appendChild( property );

        property = document.createElement( 'td' );
        property.innerText = teacher.age2;
        hr.appendChild( property );

        property = document.createElement( 'td' );
        property.innerText = teacher.age3;
        hr.appendChild( property );

        property = document.createElement( 'td' );
        property.innerText = teacher.start_date;
        hr.appendChild( property );

        property = document.createElement( 'td' );
        property.innerText = teacher.salary;
        hr.appendChild( property );

        table.appendChild( hr );
    }
}







</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to use fnUpdate function from the database library >http://legacy.datatables.net/ref